# Display sankey in old browser version

Tags: javascript, sorting, highcharts, sankey-diagram

I have problem with sorting sankey diagram in older version borwser - Chrome v49. My chart looks like this:
[sankey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKEXE.png)

How to present sankey on familiar design in older borwser? In jsfiddle in newer browser version charts looks correctly. I've implemented sorting function but it doesn't work in older browser.
My [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpfz290a/)

```
function sortData(fixedData) {
        return fixedData.sort((a, b) => b[2] - a[2]);
}

//const sortedData = sortData(fixedData);

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Sankey Diagram'
    },

    series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
        data: fixedData,
        type: 'sankey',
        name: 'Sankey demo series'
    }]
});
```

I'll be grateful for any solutions!


**EDIT**
So my script exactly look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kLv6wg3b/)
Correctly works in [OPERA v58](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmFJ5.png).
Doesn't correctly works in [CHROME v49](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je2F5.png)

Comment: What browsers exactly? Look at polyfills: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/system-requirements

Comment: It's Chrome v49. I think it's a huge problem, right? I can't upgrade because I must work on this version.

Comment: Hi @Vix, Does the chart works correctly in your environment wothout the sorting function?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, no, doesn't. I think it's problem in browser. I checked in the newest version of Opera and sankey drew correctly with sorting and without function. So, I'm using Chrome v49 in application and it can't be upgraded at this moment.

Comment: @Vix, Could you test this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z0naux92/, to find out if `sankey` does not work at all in Chrome v49 ?

Comment: @ppotaczek, so I checked and it works correctly. I checked also on my data without _function updateData_ and it works correctly. I don't have any idea what thats happens. I edited my main post and updated png with difference. My script exactly look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kLv6wg3b/)

Comment: @Vix, maybe it is caused by the sort arrow function, please test this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7fek6m0t/

Comment: @ppotaczek, no, it doesn't work

Comment: Hi Vix, It is very hard to help you, because I can not reproduce the problem. Your all chart depends on `updateData` function, so the issue can be caused by many factors. You should try to debug your code.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, I found the issue. In sorting function I had to replace fixedData to [...fixedData], and it works now. So I found another issue. How to correctly ascending sort? My [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/50gpuc4k/4/) In my first column data aren't sorted.

Comment: @Vix, Could you describe your problem more precisely? Your sorting function seems to works correctly.

Comment: @ppotaczek, sure!. Right my data are sorted by flow, no column. Please look on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/50gpuc4k/6/). All my columns are sorted ascending. First is Jhn Murray, second Patric, third Joel, etc. In [previous](http://jsfiddle.net/50gpuc4k/4/) first is Joel, second Susan, third Patric etc.

Comment: Hi Vix, Thanks for the exact explanation of the problem. I have added the solution below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort your data by the sum of the values from the same name, not by individual values:

```
const fixedData = [
    ...
];

let sum;

fixedData.forEach(function(el1) {
    sum = 0;
    fixedData.forEach(function(el2) {
        if (el2[0] === el1[0]) {
            sum += el2[2]
        }
    });
    el1.push(sum);
});

function sortData(arr) {
    return [...arr].sort(function(b, a) {
        return b[3] - a[3]
    });
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/td1ob0wg/

Comment: Wow! You're awesome, thanks a lot. Your solution is very helpful and clearly.